# Why does KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h').getKeyCode(); return 0?

Tags: java, keycode, keystroke

Why does `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h').getKeyCode();` return 0?

For example:

```
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KeyStrokeTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h');
    System.out.println(keyStroke.getKeyCode());
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
0
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This method delegates to `AWTKeyStroke.getCachedStroke(keychar, VK_UNDEFINED, 0, false);`, which basically means that `keyCode` is set to zero. It does this because it *doesn't know what else you may have pressed*, e.g <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc.

The method you are probably looking for is [`getKeyChar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTKeyStroke.html#getKeyChar()), which does return `'h'`.

Alternatively, you can call [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h', 0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(int,%20int)), which will specify the modifiers and thus will have a proper `KeyCode` value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(char keyChar), try using KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Character keyChar, int modifiers) with a modifier value of 0. In other words, use:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h', 0).getKeyCode();
```

Comment: it gives me int value 104 but KeyEvent.VK_H has 72.

Comment: VK keys don't care about upper/lowercase, so it gives the code for capital H, which is 72. 104 is the code of lowercase h.